# Convergence point in List object of Python

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have list object which basically take difference between two values. It's optimization problem where i am trying to find out value where it's closer to zero, so that i can find local minima. The list object would have values from [-100,-90,-80,...0.0001,...80,90,100].

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp

def BSM_Call(S,K,T,r,Sigma):
    d1 = (np.log(S/K) + (r+Sigma**2/2)*T) / (Sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - (Sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    Call = S*sp.norm.cdf(d1) - K*np.exp(-r*T)*sp.norm.cdf(d2)
    return Call 

ini_vol = 0.0001
rng = np.arange(0.0001,1,0.0001)
diff = []
for i in range(len(rng)):
    diff.append(67.33923210204784 - BSM_Call(4395.26,4400,31/365,0,ini_vol+rng[i]))
```

Once identified optimized point, I would like to fetch value corresponding ini_vol+rng[i].

Comment: Can you show the code for BSM_Call(). Also, I don't see why you need the numpy array. Just start with a variable set to 0.0001 then add 0.0001 to it while it's less than 1

Comment: OK - So this is Black-Scholes. What we now need to know is what you mean by the 'optimised point'. How would you define that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you're trying to find the value for Sigma that gives the closest result to zero (after subtracting the return value from BSM_Call and the constant 67.339...). Assuming that to be the case, here's what I would do:-

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp


def BSM(S, K, T, r, Sigma):
    _St = Sigma * np.sqrt(T)
    d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + Sigma**2 / 2) * T) / _St
    return S * sp.norm.cdf(d1) - K * np.exp(-r * T) * sp.norm.cdf(d1 - _St)


lo = None
ini = None
for i in range(1, 10000):
    ini_vol = i / 10000
    bsm = BSM(4395.26, 4400, 31 / 365, 0, ini_vol)
    diff = 67.33923210204784 - bsm
    adiff = abs(diff)
    if lo is None or adiff < lo:
        lo = diff
        ini = ini_vol
        if lo == 0:
            break
print(f'ini_vol = {ini:.4f}')
```

Note that I've changed BSM_Call to BSM to highlight a minor efficiency improvement therein. Also note that there's no need to build a list as you can figure it out as you work through the loop. There's a possibility of an early break so I've allowed for that